# What is the copyright status of game screenshots?

Tags: copyright

Game art is under copyright of the designer or their company. When I play the game and take a screenshot, whose is the copyright?

- Mine, because I played the game to that point and created the screenshot file;
- The designer or their company, because they made the art?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The designer/company owns the copyright to the original work, you own the copyright in the derivative work (the screenshot). However, your work is subject to whatever rights your license to use the game gives you and fair use/fair dealing.

An example of a company *attempting* to enforce copyright from screenshots/screen recordings can be seen by the [Nintendo Creators Program.](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13259/~/nintendo-creators-program-information)

Comment: Nintendo has already cancelled their "Nintendo Creators Program". Now they are not fighting with people who promote their products. More here - https://goombastomp.com/nintendo-creators-program-future/ .